# fast indexing 1D numpy array using index arrays with strictly increasing indices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I am not sure whether there is already such kind of optimization in numpy, but I was wondering whether fancy indexing in numpy can be faster when the index array is strictly increasing.

For example, in my case I have a list with indices which is already sorted. Will that make indexing faster? Or is there a way to use this knowledge to make it faster? I would say it can be faster because the program only has to walk over the old array once, without looking back.
Also, I was wondering whether it makes a difference if there are duplicates or not.

So in code:

```
in_dat = np.random.rand(100)

# sorted
out1 = in_dat[[1,2,8,15,26]]
# random
out2 = in_dat[[1,8,2,26,15]]
# random with duplicates
out3 = in_dat[[1,2,15,2,26]]
```

Is there a theoretical difference in speed here? And if not, is there another way, beside fancy indexing, to profit from the fact that my index array is strictly increasing?

Comment: using `timeit` I get `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.54 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.59 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.56 µs per loop` so I don't think it matters

Comment: @Gert Why should the program „walk over the old array“ _at all_?  You have the indices, there is no need to ”walk” as the values can be accessed directly.  The indices array/sequence is walked over from front to back.  Once.  Regardless of the order of the indices.